# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity

Tags: java, hibernate, groovy, orm

I have a groovy entity ClientInvoiceAttachmentExt which extends java entity ClientInvoiceAttachment. The ClientInvoiceAttachment has @Id annotation but still am seeing the "No identifier specified for entity" error

Here is my stack trace

```
[Mar 03 17:11:54] ERROR | org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'collaborationAPI': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.dc.apps.collaborationportal.security.service.CollaborationSecurityService com.dc.apps.collaborationportal.core.api.CollaborationAPI.security; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'collaborationSecurityService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.dc.apps.collaborationportal.feature.service.FeatureService com.dc.apps.collaborationportal.security.service.CollaborationSecurityService.featureService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'featureService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.dc.core.api.Services com.dc.apps.collaborationportal.feature.service.FeatureService.api; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'services': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.dc.core.api.SearchAPI com.dc.core.api.Services.search; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchAPI': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private transient org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.dc.core.entity.service.impl.QueryService.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.dc.core.common.exception.BaseApplicationException: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.dc.apps.collaborationportal.ebilling.model.impl.ClientInvoiceAttachmentExt

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.dc.apps.collaborationportal.ebilling.model.impl.ClientInvoiceAttachmentExt
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:686)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:4035)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3989)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1398)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:720)
    at com.dc.core.entity.support.CustomFieldsSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(CustomFieldsSessionFactoryBean.java:252)
    ... 94 more
```

My pom dependancies

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
            <!-- this is the latest version that works with lucene-core 3.0.3
                 (which we are stuck with until jackrabbit supports later versions) -->
            <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Here is my Java class

```
package com.dc.apps.collaborationportal.ebilling.model.impl;

import javax.persistence.AssociationOverride;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;

import com.dc.core.common.annotations.AttributeMetadataDefaults;
import com.dc.core.common.annotations.EventDefaults;
import com.dc.core.common.annotations.EventHandlerDefaults;
import com.dc.core.entity.model.IPersistentEntityInstance;
import com.dc.core.entity.model.impl.File;
import com.dc.core.events.enums.EventTypeEnum;
import com.dc.core.security.annotation.AttributeReadPermission;
import com.dc.core.security.annotation.AttributeWritePermission;
import com.dc.core.security.annotation.ContainerReference;

@Entity
@EventDefaults({
        @EventHandlerDefaults(eventType = EventTypeEnum.OnBeforeCreate, beanName = "checksumInvoiceAttachmentCommand"),
        @EventHandlerDefaults(eventType = EventTypeEnum.OnBeforeCreate, beanName = "encryptInvoiceAttachmentCommand") })
public class ClientInvoiceAttachment implements IPersistentEntityInstance {

    private static final long   serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long                id;

    private File                attachment;

    private String              checksum;

    private String              invoiceNumber;

    @Embedded
    @AssociationOverride(name = "fileData", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "attachment_file_data_id"))
    public File getAttachment() {
        return attachment;
    }

    public String getChecksum() {
        return checksum;
    }

    @Transient
    @AttributeMetadataDefaults(defaultDisplay = true)
    public String getFileName() {
        if (attachment == null) return "";
        return attachment.getName();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getInvoiceNumber() {
        return invoiceNumber;
    }

    public void setAttachment(File attachment) {
        this.attachment = attachment;
    }

    public void setChecksum(String checksum) {
        this.checksum = checksum;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setInvoiceNumber(String invoiceNumber) {
        this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
    }

}
```

Here is my groovy class

```
package com.dc.apps.collaborationportal.ebilling.model.impl

import com.dc.core.api.Services;

import java.util.List
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.OneToMany
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne
import javax.persistence.Cacheable
import javax.persistence.Transient
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn
import javax.persistence.Embedded
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.OneToOne
import javax.persistence.AssociationOverride
import javax.persistence.Lob
import javax.persistence.FetchType
import javax.persistence.Entity
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.DocumentId;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Store;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQueries
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited
import org.hibernate.envers.NotAudited
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type
//import org.hibernate.annotations.Index
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption
import org.hibernate.annotations.Formula
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode
import org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException
import com.dc.core.entity.enums.VersionStatusEnum
import com.dc.core.behavior.command.model.ICommandResult
import com.dc.core.behavior.command.model.impl.CommandResult
import com.dc.core.behavior.command.model.IEntityInstanceCommand
import com.dc.core.entity.model.IPersistentEntityInstance
import com.dc.core.behavior.trackchanges.model.IEntityChangeset
import com.dc.core.security.model.IContainer
import com.dc.core.security.annotation.ContainerReference
import com.dc.core.security.annotation.Encrypted
import com.dc.core.collaboration.enums.CollaborationRequestStatus
import com.dc.core.collaboration.model.ICollaborationParcel
import com.dc.core.collaboration.model.ICollaborationFeatureDetail
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy


@javax.persistence.Entity
class ClientInvoiceAttachmentExt extends com.dc.apps.collaborationportal.ebilling.model.impl.ClientInvoiceAttachment implements IAmGroovy, Serializable {

    @Autowired
    protected transient Services         services;

 private static final long                    serialVersionUID = 711967972L;
  public java.lang.String getCreatedBy() {
    return this.createdBy;
  }

  public void setCreatedBy(java.lang.String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
  }

  protected createdBy;

  public java.lang.String getUpdatedBy() {
    return this.updatedBy;
  }

  public void setUpdatedBy(java.lang.String updatedBy) {
    this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
  }

  protected updatedBy;

  public java.sql.Timestamp getCreatedAt() {
    return this.createdAt;
  }

  public void setCreatedAt(java.sql.Timestamp createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
  }

  protected createdAt;

  public java.sql.Timestamp getUpdatedAt() {
    return this.updatedAt;
  }

  public void setUpdatedAt(java.sql.Timestamp updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
  }

  protected updatedAt;

  protected transient ApplicationContext applicationContext; 

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem scenario is of Inheritance Mapping. The Id field is there in your super class but what about your child class, how they will be related to their parent.

There are different strategy to map an Inheritance hierarchy.

1. Using Discriminator value (Single Table)
2. Table per concrete class
3. Table per Child class (if parent is an abstract)

I think you are missing annotations related to above.

In Discriminator based approach.. You need to annotate your ParentClass as follows:

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)  
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)  
@DiscriminatorValue(value="ParentClass")
```

And in you child class:

```
@DiscriminatorValue("childClasss")
```

Please refer some tutorial on Inheritance Mapping like [this one](http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-table-per-hierarchy-using-annotation-tutorial-example) or you can google it.

Comment: discriminator column defaults to "DTYPE" and the discriminator type to DiscriminatorType.STRING  also the discriminator value defaults to the entity name since DiscriminatorColumn, DiscriminatorValue annotations are not specified. So adding these annotation doesnt solve my issue.

Comment: @RanPaul Are you still getting same issue `No identifier specified for entity: com.dc.apps.collaborationportal.ebilling.model.impl.ClientInvoiceAttachmentExt`? what about `@Inheritance` annotation, I hope you added it as well in you Parent Class. can you post you configuration file as well?

Comment: Yes I added @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) and I still see the org.hibernate.AnnotationException

Comment: I would suggest to read the tutorial above as I highly suspect you still have issue with Inheritance mapping. `discriminator column defaults to "DTYPE"` is not true you need to add some value in both parent and child class.

Comment: You must add @MappedSuperclass to your superclass entity

Answer (score 2):

There is a new annotation `@MappedSuperclass` that you add to the base class and it only affects the OOP without the need to change the DB. That is what I was looking for. You can read more about it [in this post](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-inherit-properties-from-a-base-class-entity-using-mappedsuperclass-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while working with JPA & I have added the  @Id annotation,

While working with JPA, kindly make sure that this @Id annotation should be from package **javax.persistence.Id** & not from **org.springframework.data.annotation.Id**.

Hope it can save your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the similar error. In case you have a Class which has a one to one relation with other class , that other class should have a Primary key as an identifier. (My app was using spring boot,jpa,h2,lombok)

Ex:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
Class A{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="b")
    public B b;
}
```

Now the similar error might be raised if you missed writing the primary key or an identifier for the class B which is shown below

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
Class b{

   /* Same error may be raised when he below code is missing*/
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long b_id;

     @OneToOne(mappedBy = "bid")
    public A a;

}
```